# How do I open the solution in my github repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, github, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019

How do I open the solution in my github repository?

Repository:
https://github.com/tux-superman/VitekSky

When I try to open it via visual studio 2019 I get the following error in my Visual Studio 2019:

```
11 [main] sh (12588) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x2717410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      1 [main] sh 16452 fork: child -1 - forked process 12588 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     22 [main] sh (2000) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x2757410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
1233409 [main] sh 16452 fork: child -1 - forked process 2000 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     14 [main] sh (7136) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x2887410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
3434849 [main] sh 16452 fork: child -1 - forked process 7136 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     16 [main] sh (10804) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x26B7410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
7664706 [main] sh 16452 fork: child -1 - forked process 10804 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     16 [main] sh (25132) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x27E7410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
15902920 [main] sh 16452 fork: child -1 - forked process 25132 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
     10 [main] sh (7204) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x2737410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      2 [main] sh 15020 fork: child -1 - forked process 7204 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     15 [main] sh (20224) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x28B7410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
1230570 [main] sh 15020 fork: child -1 - forked process 20224 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     21 [main] sh (17468) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x25E7410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
3454622 [main] sh 15020 fork: child -1 - forked process 17468 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     13 [main] sh (20592) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x2707410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
7682461 [main] sh 15020 fork: child -1 - forked process 20592 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
     22 [main] sh (23856) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\teamfoundation\team explorer\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x26E7410/0x28C7410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
15918509 [main] sh 15020 fork: child -1 - forked process 23856 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: CloneCommand.ExecuteClone
```

I have tries searching for a cygwin folder or a cygwin1.dll file but nothing shows up.

Does it perhaps have something to do with me having had folder called repos where I had the VitekAPI folder and the VitekSky folder. The two folder names are names of my projects. I had first finnished VitekSky and was able to sync it to github. Afterwards I had problems with syncing VitekSky to github so I went into the VitekSky folder and moved .gitattributes, .gitignore and the .git folder into the repos folder. After I did that I could sync the entire solution with the two projects up. I have the solution working locally I but am having problems with the github part. Your help would be appriciated.

Comment: I clone the Repository and open it with my VS2019 but its work fine no issues

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAshraf can you run the site in debug mode?

Comment: Do you have Cygwin installed at all? Do you even know what Cygwin is?

Comment: @robbpriestley No I do not..will google it and see if I can install it

Comment: I would try **un-installing** Cygwin and/or uninstalling Visual Studio and re-installing Visual Studio.

Comment: @robbpriestley Thanks I will try doing that.

Comment: Is anyone able to open up the github solution in Visual Studio and run it in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, I can open the solution in VS2019. I can also run it, but for me I am getting a "HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies" error. This is not the same problem you are having. You are stuck at an earlier stage in the process. I believe your environment is at fault. It seems probably Cygwin was installed on your  machine at some point but the installation is now bad and creating interference. Uninstall Cygwin, and Visual Studio and re-install Visual Studio.